# Running an installation program from Team City

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to execute a setup program, which requires user input, from TeamCity?

It is an MSI installer file and using all the defaults is just fine, I just need to run the installation program automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `msiexec /i foo.msi /quiet` to avoid the installer prompting.

There are other  possibly relevant options; see `msiexec /?`.